# Is it possible to use a LINQ Query in Windows Workflow rule condition?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, rule-engine

I am in the process of prototyping an implementation of a rules engine to help us with our ordering portals. For example giving discounts on items or requiring approval if certain items are ordered. We would also like to be able to add rules for dollar amounts, user hierarchy positions, and be apply it one client or more.

I feel that WWF is a good answer to this need.

All of that said however I am having a little difficulty figuring out how best to set up some of the more complex rules. I have a "condition" that I feel is best described in a LINQ query, like so:

`var y = from ol in currentOrder.OrderLines where ol.ItemCode == "MYITEMCODE" select ol;`

I am not against using a different framework for a rules engine or adding additional properties/methods to our objects (ex: `OrderHasItem(ItemCode)`, etc) to make these rules more simplified but I would like to avoid having to do that. It feels self-defeating in that it forces us down the road of potentially requiring code changes for new rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WF is a workflow engine. It's used to run factories and banks. The rule engine is just a small part of it. To make sense, any normal WF project requires a dedicated team of professionals to build it. Seems like an overkill for your specific purpose. You are very likely to bury yourself and your project in a typical fight between requirements and real skills of your team.

The use of any available .NET engine would be more justified in your situation. Keep in mind that building a custom rule engine is not an easy tasks, no matter how simple it seems from the beginning. Setting property values of a class (typically called a "fact" or "source" object) or executing actions (invoking class' methods) is what rules engines do best. And it seems that it's exactly what you need. Check out some available .NET engines. They are inexpensive, if not free, and reliable.

Comment: I think FLEE looks promising... I am concerned that it looks like it will be code intensive. I would still really like to be able to throw a LINQ query at it. A class of custom functions looks like it might be partially helpful.

Comment: Accepting this answer. I still think WF will work for what we want but I haven't been able to make it work like the examples I have seen yet. It does appear that FLEE will work, though it looks like it is more dependent on code updates to update rules than I was hoping for.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use Linq queries with Workflow.  In WF what you are referring to as a rule is an expression that is evaluated at runtime.  Your query is selecting a subset of the orderliness based on a criteria.

For example, if I have a collection of names and I want to see only names that begin with 'R'.  I could write the following code.

```
private static void ShowQueryWithCode(IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    Console.WriteLine("LINQ Query in Code - show names that start with 'R'");

    // Assuming there are no null entries in the names collection
    var query = from name in names where name.StartsWith("R") select name;

    // This is the same thing as 
    // var query = names.Where(name => name.StartsWith("R"));
    foreach (var name in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

To do the same with Workflow

**Step 1: Create a Workflow with an In Argument of type IEnumerable**

Here you can see that I've added the in argument
[image: in argument]

**Step 2: Add a Variable for the query of type IEnumerable**

Before you can add a variable you need to include an activity which has variables.  In this workflow I've added a sequence.

[image: variable]

**Step 3: Assign the query the LINQ expression you want to use**
You can use a method chain or query syntax.

[image: expression]

**Step 4: Iterate over the collection**

In the completed workflow I used a ForEach activity to iterate the list of names and write them to the console.

[image: Workflow1]

This example uses C# in .NET 4.5 but the same technique can be used with Visual Basic.

You can download the sample code [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-Linq-Queries-in-5b17f6be)

Comment: Excellent! Should this translate to be usable in a similar fashion as these examples? http://www.sanderstechnology.com/2011/a-quick-and-dirty-rules-engine-using-windows-workflow-part-2/10491/#.UBA78bSe6DM and http://www.richard-banks.org/2007/08/how-to-use-windows-workflow-rules.html

Comment: These examples are demonstrating how to use the old (WF 3.5) workflow rules engine.  I wouldn't recommend using it.  Rules can be thought of as a group of If / Then / Else statements.

Comment: @RonJacobs I know this is old, but any why I would be getting an error at run-time that I need to reference system.linq when it is in the "import" section of the hosted designer. Do I need to add something else to the actual wf engine? Thanks.